# Constraints on the lifetime of the argument to std::regex_match (and std::regex_search)

Tags: c++, c++11

Considering the C++11 function with the signaturer `std::regex_match(
std::string const&, std::smatch& match, std::regex const& re )`, what
are the constraints on the lifetime of the first argument?  I don't find
any, but when I execute the following program (compiled with VC++ 2010,
iterator debugging active):

```
int
main()
{
    std::string a("aaa");
    std::string c("ccc");
    std::regex re("aaa(.*)ccc");
    std::smatch m;
    if (std::regex_match(a + "xyz" + c, m, re)) {
        std::cout << m[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << m[1] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it crashes, doubtlessly because the `sub_match` in `m` only keep
iterators into the string, and not copies.  I can't find anything in the
standard which forbids my code.

FWIW: it didn't work in `boost::regex`, either, and that's what the
`std::regex` is based on.  (Of course, Boost didn't document any
constraints with regards to the lifetime either.)

In the end, I guess my question is: should I send in a DR to the
standards organization, or a bug report to Microsoft?

Comment: I would send a DR. Now, what should be in the DR is another issue. The options would be either just documenting or providing an overload that takes an rvalue-reference so that simple code that *looks* correct behaves correctly. [I am inclined to go for the documentation approach]

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas On what basis?  There are lots of functions in the standard which take references, and the required lifetime is never more than the function itself.  On what basis (other than what Boost did) do we assume that that wasn't the intent here?

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that this might be a bug in the implementation and that the standard might have been designed to make a copy of the argument. Yes, that is a third approach :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes.  I'm saying that I don't know what the intent was.  Pete's answer suggests that the committee didn't think of this issue, so there's no clear intent.  Which means that they'll discuss it next time around, and make a decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recall any discussion of this possibility during the adoption of `tr1::regex` or `std::regex`, so I think it simply was not considered. In hindsight, it's certainly a trap that we should have foreseen. Off the top of my head, an overload that takes a `std::string&&` would signal that a temporary is involved, and a copy is needed. So I'd report it to the Standards Committee. (full disclosure: I wrote the Dinkumware implementation, which is what Microsoft ships)

Comment: And you likely based it on Boost, which has the same problem (including the lack of documentation with regards to any requirements).  It's not usual for it to be a problem, since you don't usually try to match temporaries.  (On the other hand, I can very easily see matching a string local to a loop, with the `smatch` outside the loop, and used after the end of the loop.)

Comment: @JamesKanze - it was not based on Boost. Just a parallel lack of vision in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

The specification for this overload of `regex_match` states that it (28.11.2[re.alg.match]/6):

> *Returns:* `regex_match(s.begin(), s.end(), m, e, flags)`

There are no additional requirements on this overload, and the overload to which it delegates takes only an iterator range--there is no way for it to keep the temporary string alive because it doesn't even know that there is a string to be kept alive.

This issue came up in discussion during [STL's`regex` presentation at C++Now '12](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUZL-PRWMeg).  Someone recommended that additional overloads might be added to the specification, to catch rvalue string arguments (e.g. `basic_string<...>&&`), which would give a nice compilation error instead of this runtime error.  The library specification doesn't include those overloads, though, and I don't see a defect report for this.

Comment: The issue isn't just with rvalues.  Consider a `smatch` declared outside a loop, and calling `regex_match` inside the loop, with a string defined inside the loop.  The issue is complex: it can be made to work (by keeping a copy of the string in case of a match), so may be it should be required to work.

Comment: @JamesKanze - good point. But the implication is that the library can't, in general, detect this lifetime issue. Keeping a copy of the string is pretty heavyweight, so my inclination at this point would be to leave it as is, and tell people "don't do that". But, of course, I don't speak for the committee.

Comment: @JamesKanze:  I don't see how that is different from other lifetime issues that are not detectable at compile-time:  `{ std::vector<int> v; return v.begin(); }` is well-formed code, and there's no way to detect (in all cases) that the returned iterator is invalidated after the function returns.  At least a deleted rvalue overload would help to detect obvious misuse.  In my opinion, `match_results` is already sufficiently specified:  it only deals with iterators, which is a good indication that one should be mindful of the lifetime of the range into which they point.

Comment: @PeteBecker I think constraining the lifetime is a valid choice (as is not constraining it); I can certainly live with it if that's what the committee decides.  But if there is such a constraint, it must be explicit.  (This isn't like the other James' example, where you explicitly manipulate an iterator into a collection.  I think the standard is clear here: using an iterator after the collection ceases to exist is undefined behavior.)